Do the Xtensa ESP32 SOCs use the same or different compilers/toolchains?
I'm completely confused about Espressif's SOC family of products.
I constructed a preliminary table (maybe incorrect) below based on my understanding of their core microcontrollers and their respective toolchains. While there's a GCC toolchain directly targeting the L106 MCU, the LX6 and LX7 microcontrollers are targeted by the same toolchain. Presumably, both microcontrollers share the same ISA and thus the same compiler.
As I looked through Espressif's GCC compiler repo on GitHub, I felt completely confused when I discovered there are specific toolchains for each SOC. There's a toolchain, xtensa-esp32s3-elf, for targeting EAP32S3, as well as ESP32 and ESP32S3. Looking inside the toolchain's /bin folder, the actual GCC compilers are named after the SOC, suggesting they're specific to the microvonttoller. Alternatively, they could be the same compiler renamed to match the SOC's name.
Is my table below incorrect?



SOC
MCU
GCC toolchain




ESP8266
L106
Xtensa-lx106-elf


ESP32
LX6
Xtensa-esp-elf


ESP32-S series
LX7
Xtensa-esp-elf


ESP32-C series
RISCV32
riscv32-esp-elf


ESP32-P Series
RISCV32
riscv32-esp-elf


ESP32-H Series
RISCV32
riscv32-esp-elf




Both the Extensa and RiscV cores have a number of options, so it is not unreasonable that Espressif have their own builds of gcc. There may also be bugs in their cores, so their compilers work around these potential issues. Since you’ve mapped out the soc/compiler pairings, where’s the confusion?
